# Exclude custom taxonomy term posts from custom post loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, exclude

I have a custom post type set up called `projects` with a custom taxonomy called `categories` that has a number of terms. For one of them called `archive` I would like to remove its associated posts from the custom post loop. I'm attempting with the code below, but doesn't seem to be excluding.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'projects', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 

query_posts( array(
'post_type' =>'projets',
'tax_query' => array( 
array( 'taxonomy' => 'categories', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => array( 'archive', ), 'operator' => 'NOT IN',),)
) );
?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> POST CONTENT <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I'd love to see this solved